# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: The link to the 'site self-evaluation review queue' seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Automatically Converting Natural Language to First-Order Logic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/automatically-converting-natural-language-to-first-order-logic)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [The term for compounds mixed from different languages](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/the-term-for-compounds-mixed-from-different-languages)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Is there any agglutinative Indo-European language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/is-there-any-agglutinative-indo-european-language)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Are there any languages with only front vowels?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/are-there-any-languages-with-only-front-vowels)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How many of Latin words have Greek roots?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/how-many-of-latin-words-have-greek-roots)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How does one become a field linguist?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3734/how-does-one-become-a-field-linguist)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is there any synchronic difference between homonymy and polysemy?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/is-there-any-synchronic-difference-between-homonymy-and-polysemy)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Wouldn't a language without recursion still be non-finite at the level of discourse?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/wouldnt-a-language-without-recursion-still-be-non-finite-at-the-level-of-discou)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/what-is-the-origin-of-the-name-condoleezza

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What is a PARSE constraint in optimality theory?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3699/what-is-a-parse-constraint-in-optimality-theory)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

Answer (score 0):

"What is the origin of the name 'Condoleezza'" is the only question on this list that I would rate as less than satisfactory.

It seems to me that technical questions have been dismissed out of hand on this list.  I think that technical questions should be permitted so that the linguists on this list can be stimulated too.

I also think that some of the "far-out" questions on this list shouldn't be dismissed either.   I am thinking of "Automatically converting natural language into first order logic."   Sometimes, the experts on this list can teach us all a great deal by answering such questions.

I also suspect that the number of upvotes that a question gets on the main site represents a larger sample of opinions than the responses to this question here in meta.

Comment: I don't think these ratings are about the questions, but rather the questions+answers.  For example, I have to say that the Parse question (before I answered it, yesterday, in response to seeing it on this list) was in really embarassingly bad shape -- the only answer was the questioner attempting to reconstruct things obliquely hinted/snarked at in comments, and not really getting it right.  This is especially true combined with this question's prominence in google for relevant search terms.